# How to define Chirality and Polarity on a graph?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, physics, chemistry

Is there a concept of [Chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality) or [Polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_polarity) defined on graphs?

For example, consider a system with spin-$1/2$ (up/down polarity) particles which have also chirality (right/left).

I thought to take a simple graph representation of [Ising model](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/esi3/Ellis-Monaghan.pdf) and somehow extend it.

[image]

I would say that a graph/percolation model for [liquid-crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal) is what I am looking for at the end.

I guess a 4-coloring approach should work here. I am not sure how to state it for doing physics purposes.

Comment: I had the same question of *chirality* is a *graph* while I was solving the Karnaugh Maps. Maybe some answer to your post would solve it.

Comment: @tatan can you please share a link?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't found any reference about it

Comment: Is what you want more complicated than a (not necessarily proper) $4$-coloring of the vertices with the four possible combinations up/down and left/right?

Comment: @MishaLavrov that's what I was thinking, but I am not sure.

Comment: In that case, it might help to know what sort of problems you would want to solve about such systems.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, first we want to study phase transitions, define percolation on such a graph and apply some Fokker-Planck like equation on the evolution of such a graph.

Comment: You could consider labeling each edge $\pm 1$ depending on whether the arrows at its end agree/disagree.